# Fitting in Java Generics for this specific use scenario

Tags: java, generics

First of all sorry for the not very specific title, but i couldn't find a better and *short* descriptive one!

I've got an Interface like so:

```
public interface ModelInterface {        
    public List<? extends Umbrella> getBRs();
}
```

And and several implementing classes of this pattern:

```
public class Model implements ModelInterface {
    // need to use the concrete impl here because of JPA
    List<StoneUmbrella> _list = new ArrayList<>(); 

    @Override
    public List<? extends Umbrella> getBRs() {
        return _list;
    }
}
```

So far so good. But i also have the following Util class:

```
import java.util.Collection;

public abstract class Util<E, R> {

    public R reduce(Collection<E> collection, R initialElement) {
        R result = initialElement;
        for (E currElement : collection) {
            result = reduce(result, currElement);
        }
        return result;
    }

    abstract R reduce(R initialElement, E element);
}
```

Now the problem occurrs when i try to invoke that Utility class in my main code:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModelInterface model = new Model();

        List<? extends Umbrella> list = model.getBRs();

        Util<Umbrella, Boolean> util = new Util<Umbrella, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            Boolean reduce(Boolean initialElement, Umbrella element) {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        };

        util.reduce(list, Boolean.FALSE);
    }
}
```

The *util.reduce* line fails to compile with this message:
The method reduce(Collection, Boolean) in the type Util is not applicable for the arguments (List<capture#2-of ? extends Umbrella>, Boolean)

It works when i use List<Umbrella> instead of List<? extends Umbrella> but i can't change that in the Model Interface or i won't be able to return its internal list in the getter. I kind of think it's impossible to implement it in a way that satisfies **both** sides.

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: "It works when i use List instead of List..." ?

Comment: Sorry, the generics were filtered out because of the <> characters

Comment: Can you please specify which parts should _not_ be changed? For example, does the _list in Model have to be of StoneUmbrella type or it can be changed to generic type?

Comment: No, as the comment on that field specifies, it needs to be of the concrete implementation, else JPA issues will come up when using NamedQueries

Comment: What about the other fields/methods? Changing Util method to `reduce(Collection<? extends E> collection` solves the compilation problem but it might break logic in some other place

Comment: I actually haven't tried that approach yet! I'll fit that into my production code right away and see if it breaks anything!

Answer (score 1):

This variant compiles:

```
public class ListUmbrella {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModelInterface<StoneUmbrella> model = new Model();
        List<StoneUmbrella> list = model.getBRs();
        Util<StoneUmbrella, Boolean> util = new Util<StoneUmbrella, Boolean>() {
            @Override
            Boolean reduce(Boolean initialElement, StoneUmbrella element) {
                return Boolean.TRUE;
            }
        };

        util.reduce(list, Boolean.FALSE);
    }
}

interface ModelInterface<T extends Umbrella> {
    public List<T> getBRs();
}

class Model implements ModelInterface<StoneUmbrella> {
    List<StoneUmbrella> _list = new ArrayList<StoneUmbrella>();

    @Override
    public List<StoneUmbrella> getBRs() {
        return _list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The arguments in the generics needs to be exactly same. You can't follow the inheritance hierarchy here.
What you are trying to do is effectively

```
Collection<Umbrella> test = new ArrayList<StoneUmbrella>();
```

But you should do

```
Collection<StoneUmbrella> test = new ArrayList<StoneUmbrella>();
```

Not sure what you can do with the Model class. But I would try to change it to the following and solve it accordingly.

```
public interface ModelInterface<T extends Umbrella> {        
    public List<T> getBRs();
}
```

Let me know if you need the full code for the above solution. Don't want to overload if you can't really do anything with ModelInterface and I don't have any other good answer.

Comment: I haven't tried, but the Umbrella interface and its implementations, as well as the Model class are JPA Entities with @NamedQueries attached. I don't think JPA will be able to handle a generic Entity class.

Answer (score -1):

There is a mistake in the syntax of util.reduce method. Please correct it to:

```
 public R reduce(Collection<? extends E> collection, R initialElement)
```